# Lookahead to get values within quotes

Tags: python, regex

Without doing a python `split`, what would be the regex to get the following:

```
s = '[@Country="US"][@Language="ES"]'

["US", "ES"]
```

The current one I am using doesn't stop before the second quotation and bracket, `"]`:

```
re.findall(r'=\"(.+)?\"\]', s)
```

What would be the correct regex here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a negated character class:

```
="([^"]+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rA3jC4/2)

**Details**:

- `="`  - a literal `="` text
- `([^"]+)` - Group 1 (this will be returned by `re.findall`) 1 or more characters other than `"`
- `"` - a double quote.

**NOTE**: if there are only uppercase ASCII letters inside, you may make the pattern more precise with `="([A-Z]+)"`.

[Python demo](http://ideone.com/vqlM3E):

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'="([^"]+)"')
s = '[@Country="US"][@Language="ES"]'
print(p.findall(s))
# => ['US', 'ES']
```

Answer (score 1):

Regular expressions are greedy: means that the regex matches the biggest string possible matching your regex since you accept any character before the closing bracket.
If you accept any character BUT the closing bracket it works as you wanted.

```
re.findall(r'=\"([^\]]+)?\"\]', s)
```

or activate the non-greedy mode or regex with `+?`. Matches as soon as closing bracket is found.

```
re.findall(r'=\"(.+?)?\"\]', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regex was almost right, try this one:

```
re.findall(r'=\"(.+?)\"\]', s)
```

? Should be inside the parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

I would go with Wiktor's solution too. If you have a consistent pattern where the groups will always be enclosed in " " then something like this should do well.

```
import re

output = []

s = '[@Country="US"][@Language="ES"]'

regex = r'"([^"]+)"'

value = re.findall(regex, s)
output.append(value)

print(output)
```